# Storing and transferring credentials from a public computer

Tags: security

I have a public computer that is used in an ATM sort of fashion. When a certain action occurs (person inserts money), the program I've written on the computer sends a request to a trusted server which does a very critical task (transfers money).

I'm wondering, since I have to communicate to a server to start the critical task, the credentials to communicate with it are stored on this public computer. How do I prevent hackers from obtaining this information and running the critical task with their own parameters?

Comment: [security.se](http://security.stackexchange.com) may be a better forum for this question.

Comment: Do your users use debit cards? If so, you could tie the server-side authorization to the data obtained from these. Also, you could make your server authorize the particular IP of your ATM's connection and require staff to re-login the machine in case of connection crash or power outage. The trick here is the dynamic DHCP - the attacker can't find what IP there was before he took it down. This is not really a cryptographic solution, but it will ruin a hacker's day. I suspect this is what actual ATMs in my country do because they do hang with a connection error every so often.

Comment: Is this PC one unit including bank note acceptor, or is bill acceptor a separate, secure entity?

Answer (score 0):

[HSM (Hardware Security Modules)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) are designed to store keys safely:

> A hardware security module (HSM) is a physical computing device that safeguards and manages digital keys for strong authentication and provides cryptoprocessing. These modules traditionally come in the form of a plug-in card or an external device that attaches directly to a computer or network server.
>
> HSMs may possess controls that provide tamper evidence such as logging and alerting and tamper resistance such as deleting keys upon tamper detection. Each module contains one or more secure cryptoprocessor chips to prevent tampering and bus probing.

Answer (score 0):

**Impossible in general**

If your user has access to this PC, they can easily insert fake money. Your model is doomed.

**Minimize attack surface**

This PC ought to have unique token (a permanent cookie is enough), and sever will refuse a request without a valid cookie. Server maintains database of device types, and this ATM-PC is only allowed certain operations (deposit money up to NNN units). Ideally it is also rate-limited (at most once per 3 seconds).